# Why is this query not executing properly when using flaskext.mysql, when it executes correctly using MySQL workbench?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-mysql

So I have this query

```
query =  "SET @rownumber = 0; UPDATE students SET roll_no = (@rownumber := @rownumber+1) WHERE standard='{}' AND division='{}' ORDER BY fname, lname".format(standard, division)
```

When I try to run this query using `cursor.execute(query)`, I get this following error using

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE students SET roll_no = (@rownumber := @rownumber+1) WHERE standard='4' AN' at line 1")
```

But this same query works fine when I run it on MYSQL workbench ? Why is it not working and how can I get it to work ?

Comment: It seems this method cannot execute multiquery. Init variable in WHERE  clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE students 
SET roll_no = (@rownumber := @rownumber+1) 
WHERE standard='{}' 
  AND division='{}' 
  AND (1 + (@rownumber := 0))
ORDER BY fname, lname
```

What happens?

Execution plan builder finds constant condition `AND (1 + (@rownumber := 0))` (it does not include any column) and evaluates it once before query execution for to convert it to a constant. The value obtained is 1 which is treated as TRUE constant, so this condition is removed. But the user-defined variable initializes during evaluation.

This method allows both initialize the variable and store ORDER BY usage, because it do not convert the query to multi-table form (like when initialize the variable in subquery) in which ORDER BY clause is not allowed.

Comment: @nbk Explanations added.